# How did Welfin know about Komugi?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In episode 134, when Meruem asks about Pouf's secret to Welfin, Welfin thinks so hard, harder than his brain is capable of. And the result is that he says "Komugi".

[image: Welfin answered "Komugi...?"]

Why did Welfin know about Komugi? Did he meet her before?

Answer (score 5):

Just recently re-saw the arc so it's pretty fresh.  He knew because Pouf had him call Pitou to tell her that Killua killed her.  It struck him as a weird request at the time, but when he was racking his brain for the right answer, he started connecting all the dots and realized she was the keyword in all of it.

He most likely figured out Komugi was the right name because he put the following things together:

1. The King is looking for something.
2. King wants to know what Pouf is hiding.
3. Pouf used Welkin to lie to another Royal guard.
4. Pouf lied about the enemy killing a person named Komugi who was in the enemies' possession
5. Royal guards are incapable of being un-loyal to the King.
6. Ikalgo/Palm believes they have something the King will definitely trade for.

Answer (score 1):

In chapter 309 of the manga, Ikalgo and Palm had Welfin hidden in the back of the truck, Ikalgo never mentioned Komugi, because that was the 'secret' the narrator was talking about. And the 'secret' was to exchanging Komugi with Knuckle and Meleoron, and that was the plan.

[image: Ikalgo and Palm driving a truck with the narration "What is Ikalgo's secret plan...!?"]

Answer (score 0):

He knew because Ikalgo and Palm told him about her and asked him to relay it to meruem.

Comment: Your answer must be a good one because it has an upvote but could you include any sources or references. E.g. from the manga, episodes etc. :)

Comment: How do I add the pictures of the manga pages though

Comment: @Sopwill on the button bar above where you write you answer, there is an picture icon, it will allow you to upload image on your computer or from the web.

Comment: Can you do it from your phone because I don't see the icon on my phone.

Comment: This is not the reason. They told him to tell Meruem to talk talk to them nothing more.  He knew because Pouf had welfin make the call to Pitou which was the one out of place incident.